# How to add a pom.xml to an existing Netbeans webapplication project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, netbeans, web-applications, pom.xml

I want to add Spring Boot, but for some reason NetBeans didn't have it in the Spring framework package.

I want to add a **pom.xml** for Spring Boot to a brand new project.

Comment: I see someone voted to close this useful question as "too broad". That's understandable I suppose, but it actually has a very simple solution. Unfortunately the question was framed as an XY problem rather than addressing the core issue: _How to create a Spring Boot project on NetBeans?_ I wonder how often XY questions on SO are needlessly closed for being "too broad" because close voters focus on "Y" rather than "X".

Comment: I updated my answer to also show the **New Project** screen for NetBeans 8.2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [**NB-SpringBoot** plugin for NetBeans](https://github.com/AlexFalappa/nb-springboot). It is available using **Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins**. It is easier to copy your existing application code (if any) to a new Spring Boot project than tweaking your existing project to add Spring Boot.

After installing the **NB-SpringBoot** plugin you will need to restart NetBeans. Then you can use the Project Wizard to create a Spring Boot project: **File > New Project... > Java with Maven**, then select **Spring Boot basic project** or **Spring Boot Initializr project** to create a Spring Boot project with a suitably configured **pom.xml**:

[image: projectWizard]

---

**Updated 9/4/19**

The above screen shot is for Apache NetBeans 11.1. The **New Project** screen for creating a Spring Boot project on NetBeans 8.2 is slightly different: **File > New Project... > Maven**, then select **Spring Boot basic project** or **Spring Boot Initializr project**

[image: projectWizardNB82]

Comment: This sucks because I do not have the brand new netbeans Apache like in your picture.